# Executing/calling jquery from Wordpress Bulk Action function

Tags: jquery, wordpress-plugin-creation

Originally, I wasn't using WP_List_Table in my custom WP plugin and to execute bulk action, I use button with onClick event to call the jQuery function which has the below code;

```
<button type="button" onclick="selected_payout()" class="button">Pay Selected</button>
<button type="button" onclick="multi_withdaw()" class="button">Pay All</button>
```

Now, I decided to use WP_List_Table in my plugin and everything is working except for the bulk action. Below is the code of my prepare_items() function;

```
    public function prepare_items()
   {
    $columns = $this->get_columns();
    $hidden = $this->get_hidden_columns();
    $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();

    $data = $this->table_data();
    usort( $data, array( &$this, 'sort_data' ) );

    $perPage = get_option('dragonpay_payout_settings')['entry_per_page'];
    $currentPage = $this->get_pagenum();
    $totalItems = count($data);

    $this->set_pagination_args( array(
        'total_items' => $totalItems,
        'per_page'    => $perPage
    ) );

    $data = array_slice($data,(($currentPage-1)*$perPage),$perPage);

    $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
    $this->items = $data;
    
    $this->process_bulk_action();
   }
```

And the following is my bulk action functions, the dropdown menu is appearing in the page. However, nothing happens when clicked the apply button. I can't figure out how to effectively call the jQuery.

```
    public function get_bulk_actions() {

        return array(
                'pay_selected' => __( 'Pay Selected' ),
                'pay_all'   => __( 'Pay All' ),
        );

     }

public function process_bulk_action() {
        
        // security check!
        if ( isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) ) {

            $nonce  = filter_input( INPUT_POST, '_wpnonce', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
            $action = 'bulk-' . $this->_args['plural'];

            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, $action ) )
                wp_die( 'Nope! Security check failed!' );

        }

        $action = $this->current_action();

        switch ( $action ) {

            case 'pay_selected':
                //call the jquery selected_payout()
                break;

            case 'pay_all':
                //call the jquery multi_withdaw()            
                break;

            default:
                // do nothing or something else
                return;
                break;
        }

        return;
     }
```

This question seems to be dumb to others but I would greatly appreciate your advises and suggestions to understand how the solution on this.

Comment: i dont understand where the <script> tag will be rendered ?

Comment: Edited the question. I forgot remove those lines as I was trying something else. I just want to call these jquery functions depending on the selection in the bulk actions.

Comment: when using the onclick buttons, check the network tab which request is made. You have to skip the jquery part and call the server-action directly . You cant execute jquery on a serverside bulk-action so you have to figure out how to skip jquery